# Ubuntu 22.04 connected monitor is zoomed in

Tags: display, 22.04, display-resolution, external-monitor, scaling

I'm using newest version of ubuntu. I have laptop screen and connected monitor.
Built-in display (2800 x 1800) screen scale is set to 200% which is perfectly fine, but monitor (1920 x 1080) screen scale is 100% which seems to be zoomed in like 2x.
Is there some way how to reduce monitor scale to be like 50% ?
I have tried Fractional scaling, but that option reduced built-in display's resolution which is not what i want.
I would appreciate any helpful answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such version as newest. What if 2 years from now someone reads your question? You need an actual version in the question.

Comment: Well i guess my loDPI monitor dies within that time anyway.